# Continuity of a function which has a derivative in a point

Tags: functional-analysis

I need help in the following task:
Let $V$ and $W$ to be normed vector spaces and $IntD=D \subset V$. Show, that when $T \in Map(D;W)$ has a derivative in a point $\vec{v_{0}} \in D$ is continuous at that point.

I tried to use a definition of the Fréchet derivative, that if $T$ has a derivative in a point $\vec{v_{0}}$, $\exists \ dT(\vec{v_{0}}) \in LC(V;W) : T(\vec{v_{0}} +\vec{h})=T(\vec{v_{0}} )+dT(\vec{v_{0}} )(\vec{h})+r(\vec{v_{0}} ,\vec{h}) $

I was wondering if it is a good idea to show that a norm $||T(\vec{v_{0}} +\vec{h})-T(\vec{v_{0}} )|| \rightarrow 0 $ when $\vec{h} \rightarrow 0 $. Is it a good approach?

Comment: Yes, It is is a good idea because it proves that $T$ is continuous at $v_0$.

Comment: Observe that if $h \neq 0$ then $r(h)/\|h\|$ converges to zero and clearly $\|h\|$ also converges to zero, hence $r(h) = r(h)/\|h\|\|h\|$ converges to zero.